# Magento 2 set default language to spanish

Tags: language, magento-2.2.5

I am using Magento 2.2.5. I need to set the Default language as Spanish instead English in the Luma theme. How to set this.

Comment: Pls check here https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-spanish-language-pack.html

Comment: https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/magento-2-language-pack/ this link have many languages. You can use as per your requirement.